# Change another module state from one module in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two modules in my vuex store.

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        loading: loading 
        posts: posts
    }
});
```

In the module `loading`, I have a property `saving` which can be set either `true` or `false` and also have a mutation function named `TOGGLE_SAVING` to set this property.

In the module `posts`, before and after fetching posts, I want to change the property `saving`. I am doing it by calling `commit('TOGGLE_SAVING')` from one of the actions in the `posts` module.

```
var getPosts = function (context) {
    context.commit(TOGGLE_LOADING);
};
```

When it tried to commit, I got following error in the console

```
[vuex] unknown local mutation type: TOGGLE_LOADING, global type: posts/TOGGLE_LOADING
```

How can I mutate state in another module using `commit`?

Comment: If you are getting a response from lets say an api you will use 
    `commit('loading/TOGGLE_LOADING', response.data, {root: true})`

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Try it with following parameters as suggested [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html);

```
commit('TOGGLE_LOADING', null, { root: true })
```

If you have `namespaced` set to true (in Nuxt that's the default when in modules mode), this becomes:

```
commit('loading/TOGGLE_LOADING', null, { root: true })
```

Comment: If you're using modules and namespaces, don't forget to add the namespace to the `commit`, like `commit('namespace/TOGGLE_SAVING', null, { root: true })` or else it won't work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I just get 'unknown mutation type'.

Comment: I had a similar need and your answered solved my probelm. Thank you.

Comment: Why is root: true needed for this, was sure Nuxt should be able to figure find the other module's mutations?

Comment: @trainoasis I know this is a late answer, but… `{root: true}` is necessary to indicate that the path is root-relative (i.e., as it appears) and not relative to the current module. Nuxt knows you're using modules, but that doesn't absolve you from having to provide, in effect, fully qualified paths

Comment: does captal matter?

Comment: @geoidesic I got the same thing because I ignored the `{ root: true }` part. Once adding that in it worked like a dream. I suspect that means the path of the namespace starts from root instead of being appended to the current namespace...

Answer (score 3):

If you have used **`namespaced: true`** in your modules, there are two ways for it:

1- you should add `{ root: true }`:

```
commit('TOGGLE_LOADING', null, { root: true })
```

2- define a global action as below (e.g. *globalToggleLoading*) and call it from any modules you want by `dispatch('globalToggleLoading')`

```
globalToggleLoading: {
    root: true,
    handler({ commit }) {
      commit('TOGGLE_LOADING')
    }
  }
```

If your modules are **`not namespaced`**, you can call any mutations or actions by calling commit, dispatch:

```
commit('TOGGLE_LOADING')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [action](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) to commit mutation which defined in another module,then you will modify state in another module.

like this:

```
posts: {
  actions: {
    toggleSavingActions(context) {
      // some actions 
      context.commit("TOGGLE_SAVING"); // defined in loading module
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is how exactly I have done it. I also set "namespace: true" in both modules. But i am getting `[vuex] unknown local mutation type: TOGGLE_LOADING, global type: posts/TOGGLE_LOADING`

Comment: oh yes.by default, actions, mutations and getters inside modules are still registered under the global namespace .so you can either remove namespace property,or use commit('someMutation', null, { root: true })

Comment: In my case if I use `namespace: true`, I need to do the next: `commit('my_module_name/someMutation', null, { root: true })`

Comment: A commit is synchronous while an action is asynchronous so afaik you should not use an action to commit a mutation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also import the store, as you normally do in any js file and use it. For example:

```
// src/state/modules/posts.js

import store from '@/state/store'
...
store.commit('posts/TOGGLE_LOADING')
...
```

This works pretty well, the only donwside is that can difficult isolate tests or mock-up.

---

**Edition**: Recently I have eliminated all code using the technique I mention due the testing problems. Indeed you can always change the state of other modules following the recommended way, as in this example. Very useful if you manage auth and profile in distincts modules.

```js
logout: context => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Clear token in all axios requests
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''
    // Logout from firebase
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        // Update state in profile module
        context.commit('profile/SET_USER', null, {
          root: true
        })
        resolve()
      })
      .catch(error => reject(error))
  })
}
```

Comment: adding null + setting root true works indeed. Was wondering why this is necessary at all? nuxt should be able to figure out where external commit resides?

Answer (score 0):

Using:
Named modules, I had the same problem:

> unknown mutation type

I have a common module :
commonModule.js

```
import store from '../../';
const SET_ERROR   = 'SET_ERROR'

export default {
    state: () => ({
      error: [],
    }),
    mutations: {
        [SET_ERROR] (state, payload){
            state.error = payload
        },
    },
    actions: {
      setError ({ commit }, error) {
        commit(SET_ERROR, error)
      },
    },
}
```

Then in all other modules I had to call set error, so I called like this, which is error:

```
commit('setError', 'Socket is not defined!')
```

later I changed to this, which in my case solved the problem:

```
commit('SET_ERROR', 'Socket is not defined!')
```

I later deleted:

> namespace: true,

This form is not working:

```
commit('commonModule/SET_ERROR', 'Socket is not defined!')
```

nor this one:

```
commit('commonModule/setError', 'Socket is not defined!')
```

hope to be useful.