# call mutation from another module action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am currently playing with `vuex` to start with after getting to know bit more of `vue`.  So I started another todo with `veux`

I am able to add an item of todo after clicking add, but I do want to clear the `input` after it's done though.  I am having two store modules.

One named `todo_inputs` another one is `todos` so when `add` is clicked `addItem` action is being called from `todos` module which does a commit `setTodos`

After the commit is done, I want to clear the input of the `state` in `todo_input` but somehow I can't reach it.

I read a few stackoverflow and also vuex documentation of https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules

Lots were saying something of using namespace such as `commit('todo_input/setInputText', null { root: true })  But this does not work though...

Also, if inside the modules if I put in `{namespace: true}` pretty much my other actions would break after this is set.

these are my store modules

todo_input.js

```
const state = {
  item: null
};

const getters = {
  getInputText: ({ item }) => item
};

const actions = {
  onInput({ commit }, e) {
    commit("setInputText", e.target.value);
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setInputText: (state, item) => {
    state.item = item;
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true, // I tried adding this here which breaks my other action such as onInput()
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

todos.js

```
import api from "../../api/todo";

const state = {
  items: []
};

const getters = {
  itemList: ({ items }) => items
};

const actions = {
  // get list of todos
  fetchItems: async ({ commit }) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.fetch();
      commit("setTodos", response.data.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, "error in fetchTodos in actions");
    }
  },
  addItem: async ({ commit, rootState }) => {
    try {
      const { item } = rootState.todo_input;
      if (!item) return;

      const response = await api.create(item);
      const newTodoList = [...rootState.todos.items, response.data.data];
      commit("setTodos", newTodoList);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e, "error in add item in actions");
    }
  }

};

const mutations = {
  setTodos: (state, todos) => {
    state.items = todos;
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import todos from "./modules/todos";
import todo_input from "./modules/todo_input";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    todos,
    todo_input
  }
});
```

I read a few posts, lots were saying using namespace and it does look obvious though, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Comment: Let's figure it out, ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Comment: before we meet on skiype, see if my answer here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269592/1292050

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change another module state from one module in Vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606091/change-another-module-state-from-one-module-in-vuex)

Comment: @MichalLevý that was actually the first post I read when I was googling for this question, but I did try `commit('todo_input/setInputText', null, { root: true })` also `commit('setInputText', null, { root: true })`