# vuex empty state on logout

Tags: javascript, security, vue.js, vuex

Quick story of my problem:

1. Absolutely no data is stored in my vuex state when the page loads
2. If the user is logged in(or has info stored in `window.localStorage` and therefore gets auto logged in) my vuex store retrieves all the info from a socket that requires authentication.
3. Then the user logs out, **But my vuex state save still retains all its data**

This would be a security issue as not logged in people(or hackers) on a public pc could view what the state was before the user logged out.

I have seen [How to clear state in vuex store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295340/how-to-clear-state-in-vuex-store)
But I feel that this is a hack and should be avoided.

My current solution is just to refresh the page using `location.reload();`

> Is there a better way to prevent this data leak?

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @DenysKotsur Not really, my solution was to store the start state and call `replaceState(start_state)`, but this isn't such a great solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All **objects** stored in Vue act as an **observable**. So if the **reference** of a value is **changed/mutated** it triggers the **actual value to be changed too**.

So, In order to **reset** the state the **initial store modules** has to be **copied as a value**.

On logging out of a user, the same value has to be **assigned for each module** as a copy.

This can be achieved as follows:

```js
// store.js

// Initial store with modules as an object
export const initialStoreModules = {
    user,
    recruitment,
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
    /**
     * Assign the modules to the store 
     * using lodash deepClone to avoid changing the initial store module values
     */
    modules: _.cloneDeep(initialStoreModules),
    mutations: {
        // reset default state modules by looping around the initialStoreModules
        resetState(state) {
        _.forOwn(initialStoreModules, (value, key) => {
            state[key] = _.cloneDeep(value.state);
        });
        },
    }
});
```

Then call `commit("resetState");` when the user logs out.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. In reset state mutation, the value of the state for each module is not the initial value, but the last snapshot of it.

Comment: could you try 

state[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value.state))

Comment: My final solution was based on another popular answer on SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51653116/4224951

Comment: that surely helps

Comment: Good answer. `Object.assign()` must be used to maintain reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

**Normal Approach**

If user logs in, then you can add few boolean flags to ensure that user has been loggedin/loggedout.

So initial approach would be -

```
this.$store.commit('insertToken', {realtoken, isLoggedIn: true})
```

In vuex than,

```
insertToken (state, payload) {
  state.token = payload.realtoken
  state.isLoggedIn = payload.isLoggedIn
  localStorage.setItem('token', payload.realtoken)
}
```

And when user logs out you should set all flags to false,
In component -

```
logout () {
    this.$store.commit('logOut')
    this.$router.replace('/login')
  }
```

and in vuex,

```
logOut (state, payload) {
  state.token = null
  state.isLoggedIn = false
  localStorage.setItem('token', null)
},
```

So by means of `isLoggedIn` and `token` you can tell router where to navigate by using term called [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Example -

```
const checkToken = () => {

if ((localStorage.getItem('token') == null) || 
 (localStorage.getItem('token') == undefined)) {
  return false
 } else {
   return true
 }
}

// Navigation guards
if (to.path === '/') {
 if (checkToken()) {
   next()
 } else {
  router.push('/login')
 }
```

}

This is the way I use when authentication is done by means of using `token` as part of interacting with Vuex.

Comment: So how does this empty all the state ( as in all state in all modules)?

Comment: @DrevanTonder So you can do a `replaceState` API call as `this.$store.replaceState({});`. This will clear state with empty object. Link - https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html

Comment: Hmm. Well if there is interaction done with localStorage, then its sure this wouldn't help. I'll look up for possible solution. Meanwhile there are great devs on DISCORD community. You can share your problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

This extension does a nice job
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-extensions

With it installed I can just call reset in the Vuex Logout Action

```
logout(context) {
  
    // do the logout stuff, such as 
    context.commit("setUser", {});

    // On logout, clear all State, using vuex-extensions
    this.reset();

    // if using router, change to login page   
    router.replace("/login");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but I found **window.localStorage.removeItem('vuex')** useful. Thanks to Thomas von Deyen, https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist/issues/52#issuecomment-413913598

Comment: That works if you're using [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist) (And I do that in one of my newer applications). But that won't empty the state in a normal vuex store.

Comment: @DrevanTonder thanks, is it a good practice for logout functionality especially when using vuex-persist in almost everything in the app

Comment: Well, it works, but since it's a hack to empty vuex I wouldn't call it a good practice. It's using vuex-persist to do something it's not intended for. But if you didn't want to store empty states in your store and store modules you could justify using `localStorage.removeItem('vuex')`.